Optimize string aggregation for large dataset
I have two tables in SQL Server:
Product: contains product details (ID, ProductName, ...).



ProductID
ProductName




1
Product A


2
Product B



ProductEan: contains multiple code for each product (ID, ProductID, Ean).



ProductID
Ean




1
123456789012


1
987654321098


2
111111111111



The goal is to aggregate all Ean values for each product into a single row, with the EANs concatenated into a single string separated by commas.
Desired result:



ProductID
ProductName
Eans




1
Product A
123456789012,987654321098


2
Product B
111111111111



I am currently using the following query:
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    p.ProductName,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + pe.Ean
           FROM ProductEan pe
           WHERE pe.ProductID = p.ProductID
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Eans
FROM 
    Product p;
+ some JOIN to other tables

However, this query has performance issues because the ProductEan table has over 300,000 rows. It takes a very long time to execute.
I also tried using CROSS APPLY to avoid the correlated subquery, as shown below:
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    p.ProductName,
    e.Eans
FROM 
    Product p
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         STUFF((SELECT ',' + pe.Ean
                FROM ProductEan pe
                WHERE pe.ProductID = p.ProductID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Eans) e;
+ some JOIN to other tables

While this slightly simplifies the query structure, it did not improve the performance significantly.
How can I optimize this aggregation for large datasets?

Why not use STRING_AGG?

STRING_AGG is not supported in my current SQL Server version.

What version are you using then? STRING_AGG is available in both fully supported versions of SQL Server as well as 2017 and 2019. Perhaps the solution is to upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server.

Did you try creating indexes ? If its not real - time, you could also try creating batch jobs or a materialized view?

I have SQL Server 2008. Upgrade is not possible.
About indexes, yes i have, on table ProductCode index on column ProductID INCLUDE Ean.

2008 has been completely unsupported for well over 5 years; using such an outdated, insecure version is a significant concern for you, your employer, and most especially your clients. Getting yoir Server upgraded is about 6 years overdue; that it'll likely improve the performance of your query should be seen as the final nail in that coffin (that probably already has far too many nails already).

nothing I can do about it.

There is; feed back to your employer. Using such an outdated of date version is negligence at best. If your employer is demanding you make the query faster, then telling them they need to give you the tools to do so isn't a big ask (especially when they should have done so years ago).

300k shouldn't take a lot of time, what are you running sql server on, raspberry pi? You can convert cross apply to correlated subquery perhaps

Can you [edit] your question to Paste the Plan?

How many EAN max are you expecting per ProductID?


How can I optimize this aggregation for large datasets?

Try specifying ./text())[1] as the xquery expression like the example below. This can help optimize the XML concatenation method with large datasets as detailed in this answer.
As to whether this will improve performance for your query also depends on many other factors that influence the overall execution plan.
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    p.ProductName,
    e.Eans
FROM 
    Product p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + pe.Ean
            FROM ProductEan pe
            WHERE pe.ProductID = p.ProductID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Eans
) e;


You can also use recursive CTE, which can be faster than XML operations if the number of EAN parts is limited; like this:
with MyTblNumbered as (
select 
   Id
   , ProductID
   , Ean
   , Seq=row_number() over (partition by ProductId order by id)
from MyTbl)
, Combined as (
    select ProductId, EAN, sw.Seq, CombinedEAN=cast(EAN as varchar(max)), Lvl=0
    from MyTblNumbered sw
    union all
    select p.ProductId, t.EAN, t.Seq, CombinedEAN=p.CombinedEAN  + t.EAN, Lvl=p.Lvl+1
    from MyTblNumbered t
         inner join
         Combined p
         on t.ProductId=p.ProductId
         and t.Seq=p.Seq+1
), Renumbered as (
select c.* , RevSeq=row_number() over (partition by ProductId order by Lvl desc)
from Combined C
)
select *
from Renumbered 
where RevSeq=1


I have only processed your ProductEAN table; you can start joining other tables after the last step.

A recursive CTE is unlikely to provide a performance benefit, if I am honest (probably the opposite). As the name suggests, it's recursive, and SQL Server's forté is not iteration.

On a separate note, you are "breaking" the syntax highlighting in your posts (1, 2, 3, 4 and more ), because you are using \`` -lang-sql. it should be ```lang-sql`.

Thanks @thom_a. I will use the correct notation. On the subject of recursive CTE, consider this: say on average, most parts have 2 Eans, then the number of recursive iterations is two. This can be better than  building and shredding XML documents for 300k rows. Don't rule it out before understanding the data and/or testing. I didn't claim that it will certainly be faster.

If you have limited number of EAN per ProductID, you may try the pivot query either with the CASE.. expression or PIVOT operator.
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.ProductName, e.Eans
FROM    Product p
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  ProductID,
                    Eans    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Ean END)
                            + MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ',' + Ean ELSE '' END)
                            + MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ',' + Ean ELSE '' END)
                            + MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ',' + Ean ELSE '' END)
                            + MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN ',' + Ean ELSE '' END)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT  ProductID, Ean, 
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY Ean)
                FROM    ProductEan 
            ) e
            GROUP BY e.ProductID
        ) e       ON p.ProductID    = e.ProductID


For SQL Server 2008
add function to simulate string agg
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.StringAgg
(
    @ProductID INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @Result = COALESCE(@Result + ',', '') + ean.Ean
    FROM ProductEan ean
    WHERE ean.ProductID = @ProductID;

    RETURN @Result;
END

    SELECT 
    prd.ProductName,
    dbo.StringAgg(prd.ProductID) AS EanList
 FROM Product prd
GROUP BY prd.ProductID,prd.ProductName

For others versions
Others
    SELECT prd.ProductName 
           ,STRING_AGG(ean.Ean,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ean.Ean desc) as Ean
      FROM Product prd
INNER JOIN ProductEan ean on prd.ProductID = ean.ProductID
  GROUP BY prd.ProductName

